# Jquery on curl fetched data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, curl

I have a div which is being populated through curl from another html page. Now the data is populating correctly but I want to use jQuery or Javascript on the ids or classes of the fetched data.
I tried using livequery, binding but of no use.
Can you please help me?

Comment: Can you share some code?  There should be no issue with this as the curl'ed data is included server side by the php and the jquery is done client side.  So I suspect it's just an issue with the jquery/html/css code.

Comment: The code is on my laptop and i am in office so out of resources for moving the data between them.

The problem is neither with the server side code nor with the html/css .

If i apply javascript to the fetched data after it is being fetched it works but i want to use bind events to the data before it is being curled so that when fetched i dont need to and they are already binded.

Comment: Maybe try to debug it in Firebug, see if the populated data have the ids or classes that you needed. livequery only bind for a limited event, such as click. Please provide the code, or the URL, so other user can help you more accurately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you wrapping your javascript with $(document).ready(function() { } ); as to ensure the dom is fully loaded?

For instance:

```
$(document).ready(function() { $('#id').click(function() { // do stuff } ); }
```

This would fix the issue if the HTML fetched via CURL is being populated via a direct post-back.   If you're populating the data asynchronously, then you'll either have to use the .live() mechanism for binding (through read the docs carefully, live() doesn't work in certain scenarios and was added in the most recent version of jQuery -- so check that you've got the right version of jQuery and that you're not trying to use events that aren't supported with that binding mechanism).   Furthermore, live is a bit of performance tax, so I'd do something like.

```
$.ajax({ // Lots of ommitted options for simplicity's sake 
          success: function(data, status) { 
               $('#targetDiv').append(data);
               $('#targetDiv #elementID').click(function() { // do stuff });
          }
        });
```

Hopefully this helps steer you in the right direction.   With a code sample we could certainly help more.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you're trying to bind to elements that do not yet exist. JavaScript works directly on the DOM (Document Object Model). What that means, is that whenever a specific element does not yet exist in the DOM, JavaScript can't bind to it.

Using jQuery does not change this, or (at best) only does so under very specific circumstances. I would just write a wrapper function in which you bind to the new elements, that you call after the AJAX request was completed successfully.